# toXmlString analog in XmlService?

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

currently I am trying to rewrite my old script which uses Xml, the only trouble I have is that I cannot find in XmlService documentation any method similar to .toXmlString() from Xml.
This issue isn't critical since I was using it for debug purposes only, but if possible I'd like to keep this functionality.
tl;dr; The question is - how can I get raw xml string representation of element in new google's XmlService? I tried almost all methods of Element class and none of them produce this

Not sure if this specific info would be helpful or not - I am using google script to populate google sheet from rss feed.
Below is a simple code snippet I used for testing various XmlService methods. I left items[0].getValue() which I used to confirm that I have correct items array with real data (in log I see all values of subelements, concatenated into single string)

```
var stream = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText()
var xmldata = XmlService.parse(stream);
Logger.log("XMLDATA fetch from " + url)

var channel = xmldata.getRootElement().getChild('channel')
var items = channel.getChildren("item")
Logger.log("Items count: " + items.length)
Logger.log(items[0].getValue())
return
```

To be precise, instead of getValue() I need some method that would convert inner xml object into it's string representation

Comment: Did you mean 'old' Xml-based code or new XmlService one? I appended new one, since this is what I need to write.

Answer (score 2):

Found an answer - Element class doesn't have this functionality anymore, it's been moved to global XmlService, like this:

```
XmlService.getCompactFormat().format(items[0])
```

produces what I need - one text line containing xml-formatted items[0] element